Flutter Camera - how to know which camera is 0.5x or ultra wide?
I'm trying to create a feature where the user can switch to 0.5x mode but it's almost impossible to tell which camera is the ultrawide one. When I print out the list of available cameras, I see this:
[CameraDescription(com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:0, CameraLensDirection.back, 90), CameraDescription(com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:1, CameraLensDirection.front, 90), CameraDescription(com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:2, CameraLensDirection.back, 90), CameraDescription(com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:5, CameraLensDirection.back, 90)]
But how do I know which one is the ultrawide one?
I tried printing all the available cameras and looking at documentation.
